# How to display Site Name using Custom Block Layout at left corner of header, somehow it is displayed at right side

Tags: blocks

I am using Drupal 8.2.6, and instead of showing sitename from Configuration Parameter, trying to disply it with custom block. Custom block will use a png file with specific font design for site name.

I named this custom block as header, and placed it in Header position in block layout.

Problem I am facing is by default it will be placed at right corner of the header, regardless of any css vaule. However I need to display it at left side, where site name is displayed by default.

Am sure my header block is correct in terms of css left position settings, because if same block is placed at content  or footer, it will be displayed at left side only, however in header, it will go to right side.

Let me know please if any suggestion

http://timetracker.fivekittens.com/

Comment: This is a basic CSS issue. `.region-header .block {}` has a `float: right` in a media query `@media (min-width: 461px)`.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention I am using Bartik theme, can you suggest where this css is located.

Comment: That is not part of the default bartik theme. Disable CSS aggregation, clear cache en see what file it comes from.

Comment: Hi, thank you for suggestion... I realized..bartik have some kind of limitation for such customization... I changed to Mayo Theme..and this issue was not there..